# Copy / overwrite file to node_modules on npm install / start

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, angular, npm

iam setting up jQuery for my Angular2 Application, jQuery now works fine, but I get the following error on startup, build is also not possible:

```
/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:3249:13
 Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '$' must be of type 'cssSelectorHelper', but here has type 'JQueryStatic'.
```

The workaround for this is to edit the last lines in the `/node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts:3249:13`
from:

```
declare module "jquery" {
    export = $;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
declare var $: JQueryStatic;
```

to

```
declare module "jquery" {
  export = jQuery;
}
declare var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
```

Is it possible to copy the edited file automatically to the @typings/angular folder on build start or npm install?

I need to avoid manual changes.

I already tried:     `"jquery": "file:overrides/typings/jquery/index.d.ts",`

and :  `"@types/jquery": "file:overrides/typings/jquery/index.d.ts",`

I found this solutions in the web, but they are both not working.

Would be great if this can be done without installing other dependencies.

EDIT:
Now I also tried to load the whole @/typings/jquery folder with my customized index.d.ts file with:

```
"@types/jquery": "file:overrides/@types/jquery",
```

but still the file without my custumized file is installed.

Comment: Are you using protactor?

Comment: Yes protractor is included in my project.